# Django: Get Model Name by a dynamic condition

Tags: python, django

I have tables split up by world regions/continents to avoid primary key conflicts. My Model name is `Customer"<RegionName>"` where the `RegionName` is like `NA` for North America, `OCE` for Oceania, `EU` for Europe, `ASIA` for Asia, `SEA` for South East Asia, etc.

In my view, I need to get use the correct model based on the region specified in the url. My URL structure is `/fetch/customer/{region}/{customerName}`. How can I get the correct Model based on what is given as the `{region}` parameter? I know I can do a bunch of `if else` conditionals but that seems rather silly when dealing with multiple regions.

If there like way where I can have base string `Customer` and append `region` to it? Like if region given was `NA`, our string would be `Customer` + `NA` = `CustomerNA`. How can I take this `CustomerNA` string and get the actual Model class named `CustomerNA`?

Not sure if that is a little confusing to follow. Please tell me if it's hard to understand. It might have sounded a bit better in my head and got lost in translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be:

```
CUSTOMER_MODELS = {
    'NA': CustomerNA,
    'EU': CustomerEU,
    'Asia': CustomerAsia,
    #...
}
```

and to consume it,

```
model = CUSTOMER_MODELS.get(region)
```

If you can re-visit your models, I would recommend you do make it simpler (You know the business requirements though) - Example

```
class Customer:
    ...
    region = models.CharField(choices=(('NA', 'NA'), ('Asia', 'Asia'), ))
```

Then you can do away with all the complicated logic